# PDFに画像を挿入して押印のように見せたい

Tags: google-apps-script, 画像, pdf

PDFに、いわゆる電子署名ではなくて、画像の印影によるナンチャッテ判子をプログラムで押す方法はありますか？GASが望ましいですが、他の言語でもいいです。

Comment: Adobeのコミュニティに聞いたほうが良いかもしれないですね。ただPDFの作成や編集はあくまでAdobeが有料のソフトで提供しているものなので、そもそも無料でPDFを編集できるのかはわかりませんが。

Comment: https://community.adobe.com/t5/jp/ct-p/jp

Comment: ありがとうございます。PDFはもはやAdobe社の独占的なフォーマットではなく、仕様がISO 32000-1として公開しており、多くのフリーウェアが（インタラクティブで、ソースは公開されていませんが）PDFの編集機能を実装しているので、それをユーザープログラムから操作するライブラリがあるのか知りたくて、ここに質問した次第です。

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format